# exit equivalent in D?

Tags: d

After searching the documentation over at the official ([D 2.0 site](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/)) I have been unable to find an equivalent in D for the C function [*exit*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/exit/). Searching on Google failed me as well.

So I'd like to know if the function does simply not exist or if there are any other ways to "get there".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
import std.c.process;

void main() {
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Most, if not all, of the std C lib is available. *All* of it can be called if you can find/write the needed declarations.

Comment: It actually depends: on Windows, dmd links to the D runtime lib and then Digital Mars' C runtime lib, so you can call undeclared standard C functions, but on Linux dmd just links to a unified D runtime lib with the proper C functions in it, so I found that I wasn't able to call obscure C runtime functions from Linux. Your experiences may vary.